# How can I check if an ideal has a direct sum decomposition? [GAP]

Tags: gap

I need a function to check if a left ideal of a Group Algebra has a direct sum decomposition or not. So, I need a function that return true if the left ideal has a direct sum decomposition or false if the left ideal doesn't have a direct sum decomposition (so the left ideal is irreducible). Just a function that verify if a left ideal is irreducible can help too.
Is there a function to do this?

I have already created a list N with all the left ideals of R. And I have created another list B, where the left ideals are not repeated. Now, I need to check if these ideals that are on list B are irreducible, so I thought about checking if they are a direct sum of other ideals.

```
LoadPackage("wedderga");
G:=SymmetricGroup(3);
F:=GF(5);
R:=GroupRing(F,G);
N:=[]; 
for x in R do 
    I:=LeftIdeal(R,[x]);
    Add(N,I);
od;

B:=[]; 
for i in [1..Length(N)] do
    if not (N[i] in B) then
        Add(B, N[i]);
    fi;
od;
```

Comment: Cross-posted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66702368/how-can-i-check-if-a-ideal-has-a-direct-sum-decomposition-gap (I flagged it for migration there, but it's not yet dealt with).

Comment: Will it help to have a complete set of orthogonal idempotents?

Comment: I believe so. But I don't know a function that calculate all the orthogonal idempotents from a Group Algebra.

Comment: Please see Wedderga manual [here](https://gap-packages.github.io/wedderga/doc/chap4.html#X7DF49142844C278D). For your example, `PrimitiveCentralIdempotentsByCharacterTable` returns a list which then passes `IsCompleteSetOfOrthogonalIdempotents` check.

Comment: Also, useful to search in GAP using `?` or `??` - try e.g. to enter `??idempotents` and see all manual entries containing this string. I have explained this in the [GAP Carpentries-style lesson here](https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/gap-lesson/01-command-line/index.html), together with `SetHelpViewer` command you can configure it to show HTML pages from your local GAP installation in the browser.

Comment: I got bilateral ideals using the results of `PrimitiveCentralIdempotentsByStrongSP` . But now I have to find the left irreducible ideals. So, there are some ideals that are not generated by primitive idempotents. And I don't know a function that calculates orthogonal idempotents, `IsCompleteSetOfOrthogonalIdempotents`, just checks if a list has only orthogonal idempotents.

Comment: [This chapter](https://gap-packages.github.io/wedderga/doc/chap4.html) has some more functions for special cases - is says when it guarantees to return a complete one, and when it produces a warning when it's not (and you can always check the output with `IsCompleteSetOfOrthogonalIdempotents`) afterwards. GAP also has [CentralIdempotentsOfAlgebra](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap62_mj.html#X82571785846CF05C), but it may be unable to handle large examples which you are trying to tackle with Wedderga.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try. But I also need something else. Is there a function that checks whether two rings are isomorphic? I know that there is a function that checks if two groups are isomorphic, but I don't know about rings.

Comment: Not really. There is no generic function for that. You can enter `??isomorph` in GAP to see all manual sections - may find something for special cases, like https://gap-packages.github.io/modisom/htm/CHAP004.htm or https://gap-packages.github.io/sophus/doc/chap3.htm for example.